# SymPy 2nd order differential equations dsolve error

Tags: python, sympy

I want to get symbolic solution for the system of differential equations. dsolve gives an "NotImplementedError". diff(t, 1) works well. What is the best way to get the solution? Or how to convert it to the first order to solve it numerically if symbolic solution is not possible. Any help will be appreciated.

```
import sympy as sp
import mpmath
from sympy import Function, symbols, dsolve, Derivative, erf, sqrt, power, diff

a, t, rx, ry = symbols('a t rx ry')
rx = Function("rx")(t)
ry = Function("ry")(t)
r = sqrt(rx**2+ry**2)

eq1 = sp.Eq(rx.diff(t,2), -rx/r**3)
eq2 = sp.Eq(ry.diff(t,2), -ry/r**3)
sol = dsolve([eq1, eq2])
print(sol)
```

r' = v
 v' = -r/|r|^3
To solve it numerically need to convert this to first order. It is clear that right side is the gradient:

```
grad(1/r) = -r/|r|^3
```

But for the cartesian it looks strange because of |r| and i am getting stuck how to use odeint here:

```
rx' = vx
ry' = vy
vx' = -rx/|r|^3
vy' = -ry/|r|^3
```

to use odeint i need function of 5(?) parameters and it should be like this?

```
def F(U, t):
  vx, vy, rx, ry = U
  r = np.sqrt(rx**2 + ry**2)
  rxdt = vx
  rydt = vy
  vxdt = -rx/r**3
  vydt = -ry/r**3
  return [vxdt, vydt]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SymPy doesn't have solvers implemented for this kind of nonlinear equation:

```
In [2]: eq1                                                                                                                       
Out[2]: 
  2                              
 d                  rx(t)        
───(rx(t)) = ────────────────────
  2                           3/2
dt           ⎛  2        2   ⎞   
             ⎝rx (t) + ry (t)⎠   

In [3]: eq2                                                                                                                       
Out[3]: 
  2                              
 d                  ry(t)        
───(ry(t)) = ────────────────────
  2                           3/2
dt           ⎛  2        2   ⎞   
             ⎝rx (t) + ry (t)⎠
```

Are you sure that there is any analytic solution though? If I understand correctly what you have here is like `d2r/dt^2 = r/|r|**3` which is similar to the equations for a gravitational orbit (except that would have a minus sign). In the case of the gravitational orbit I don't think there is a closed form solution for `r` in terms of `t`.